# Java enum elements with spaces?

Tags: java, enums

Im working on java, I have created an enum as follows:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    india,
    russian,
    england,
    north America
}
```

Above example gives errors while using space in the name of element (i.e. north America).
Any suggestions how to resolve above issue?

Comment: Access to this member wouldn't be possible as well; think about `myEnum x = myEnum.north America`. These won't be compiable because if one would allow such names, where to set the end of an identifier? Maybe the next code line or statement should be included?

Comment: Do NOT use small letters for enums and even for class name!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can't put a space in the middle of an identifier.

Doing so ends that identifier and the parser assumes whatever comes next is a valid token in that statement's context. There are few (if any) places that would be legal.

Conventional Java value names would be:

```
INDIA,         // Or India,
RUSSIA,        //    Russia,
NORTH_AMERICA; //    NorthAmerica;
```

An `enum` can have associated properties, like human-readable names, e.g.,

```
public enum CountryAndOneContinent {
    INDIA("India"),
    RUSSIA("Russia"),
    NORTH_AMERICA("North America");

    private String displayName;

    CountryAndOneContinent(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String displayName() { return displayName; }

    // Optionally and/or additionally, toString.
    @Override public String toString() { return displayName; }
}
```

---

I'm ambivalent about using `toString` to provide presentation-layer representations.

I prefer methods communicate their purpose explicitly–it's more expressive and obvious.

`toString` is pretty generic, and allows only a single representation. Multiple output formats may be required depending on context, parameters, etc. which `toString` doesn't allow.

Advantages of `toString` include using default string operations on the object, and in this case, using `valueOf` to directly translate from the human-readable version to the enum value.

Comment: You might want a different name than name... (Only one element in the OP is a real country. A country, a language, a constituent country and a continent. Quite an enumeration.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the issue with `toString()`. You could ofcourse add a `getDisplayName()` method instead of using `toString()`.

Comment: @Jesper Yeah, I suppose for things that look specifically for `getXxx`--I left it un-JavaBeany.

Comment: hahaha!! "and one continent" :'D hilarious. love semantic code :p

Comment: @davogotland Technically I should have gone with Tom's `CountryLanguageFederationContinentEtc` but it seemed a bit verbose.

Comment: An advantage of overriding toString() is that this string can also be used in CountryAndOneContinent.valueOf(myString).  So overriding toString basically creates a HashMap of the enum values.

Comment: @Joe True; one reason I'm ambivalent instead of vehemently opposed. When it comes to enums my stance is somewhat softened precisely for that reason :)

Comment: toString is a property that is meant to be overridden.  So your descriptive label might be the best name.

Answer (score 17):

I'm gong to go ahead and guess why you want a space in the name; because you want to reference it as a string.

So do this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    INDIA("India"),
    RUSSIAN("Russian"),
    ENGLAND("England"),
    NORTH_AMERICA("North America");    

    private String name;

    MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }    
}
```

You can consider overriding string.

```
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

An advantage of overriding toString() is that this string can also be used in MyEnum .valueOf(myString).  So overriding toString basically creates a HashMap of the enum values.

Comment: Unless I'm mssing something, this example does not work in Java 8; `MyEnum.valueOf("North America")` and `MyEnum.valueOf(MyEnum.NORTH_AMERICA.toString())` both throw the same error: `IllegalArgumentException No enum constant ofi.devops.cmwf.model.trigger.MyEnum.North America`

Answer (score 6):

The problem has nothing (specifically) to do with enums: in Java, names can't have spaces.  Try eliminating the space (using capitalization to tell the bits apart) or use underscores instead.

Answer (score 2):

Write them together like `northAmerica` or use an underscore `north_America`.

Comment: Thanks Tudor, but i don't want to do like above as u said. need to keep that words separated.

Comment: @BSalunke You can't. You could create an `enum` with a value, though. See update.

Comment: Just to emphasize what Dave Newton is saying: You can't, it just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java naming rule](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#40625) does not allow white spaces as possible characters in a name of variables, classes, enums and enum members (and every other identifier). Therefore this "problem" cannot be resolved. Just use `north_america' as member name!

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> The Java letters include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access preexisting names on legacy systems.
>
> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).

Comment: That's a syntax error, you can write a compilable code without following the convention.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, but for my understanding it should be called convention :-)

Comment: `public enum myEnum` here he is not following the convention. But `north America` is a syntax error and it won't compile.

Comment: The above section of the java manual describes how to name identifiers with respect to the allowed character

Comment: It's the **syntax (rule)** which if you don't follow then your code won't compile. Convention is something that's recommended to follow. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 2):

I also introduced an own valueOf method. But I return with the Enum Type and I do not have to convert the "checkString"

checkString is "Petty Cash" for example.

```
JournalType journalType = JournalType.valueOfOrDefault(checkString);
```

With the following enum:

```
public enum JournalType {

MISC_BILLING("Misc Billing"),
MISC_BILLING_AUTONUM("Misc Billing AutoNum"),
PRETTY_CASH("Petty Cash"),
RECURRING_AP("Recurring AP"),
GL_JOURNAL("GL Journal"),
GDS_NDS("GDS/NDS");

private final String journalType;

JournalType(String journalType) {
    this.journalType = journalType;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return journalType;
}

public static JournalType valueOfOrDefault(String myValue) {
    for(JournalType type : JournalType.class.getEnumConstants()) {
        if(type.toString().equals(myValue)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("JournalType not found");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

just make your own valueOf like function in your enum class.  Replace spaces with underscores. name your enum constants like this "north_america("North America")".  If the method fails to find your enum it just returns the parameter.

```
public  static String valueOfOrDefault(String myValue) {
//replace space with underscore so it matches enum name
        String value=myValue.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s", "_");
        for(myEnum type : myEnum.class.getEnumConstants()) {
          if(type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return type.toString();
          }
        }
        return myValue;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum myEnum
{
    india,
    russian,
    england,
    north_america
}
```

To access values

```
myEnum.values()
```

Comment: Do NOT use small letters for enums and even for class name!

Comment: @banterCZ sic erat scriptum