# How to access string with two keywords like "good time" in a switch statement in a Java?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java enum elements with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389150/java-enum-elements-with-spaces)

Below is the sample code:

```
  public enum InstrumentType{

        GUITAR,BANJO,MANDOLIN,DOBRO, FIDDLE ,LAMBEG DRUM,

        public String toString(){
            switch(this){
            case GUITAR:
                return "Guitar";
            case BANJO: 
                return "Banjo";
            case DOBRO:
                return "Dobro";
            case FIDDLE:
                return "Fiddle";

            case LAMBEG DRUM:
                return "Lambeg drum";

            default: 
                return "Unspecified";
            }
        }

}
```

how  to access two keywords like  "Lambeg drum" in switch case ?
I dont want to use LAMBEG_DRUM or LAMBEGDRUM.
 any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: enum identifiers have to follow the same naming rules as variables in Java, so you cannot use spaces to begin with.

Comment: Since you can't even declare `LAMBEG DRUM` (identifiers can't have spaces), i'm not seeing the use case...

Comment: ok but how to achieve this ? means is there another way?

Comment: Jesus...just abide by Java's syntax rules.

Comment: Use an underscore.  Spaces won't work (at least not without some reflection or dynamic-class voodoo, and even then you can't use it the way you want to).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a case statement in your toString() method. You would still have to use LAMBEG_DRUM or something without spaces in your enum name, but you can add a description to the constructor and use that in your toString().

```
    public enum InstrumentType {
            GUITAR("Guitar"), //
            BANJO("Banjo"), //
            MANDOLIN("Mandolin"), //
            DOBRO("Dobro"), //
            FIDDLE("Fiddle"), //
            LAMBEG_DRUM("Lambeg Drum");

            private String description;

            private InstrumentType(String description) {
                    this.description = description;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                    return description;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The value that goes after the keyword `case` is an identifier, or something that evaluates to a constant value (such as an integer, enum, or boolean value).

Identifiers in Java cannot have spaces in them.

It seems that your question is essentially about valid naming in Java, and the solution you propose is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In short: "you can't". Java variable/class identifiers can't contain spaces. There are some truly frightening hacks around this rule, but there's really no reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, the name "LAMBEG DRUM" is *not* a valid enum identifier, you can't have a space there, and also can't have it in the switch. use a "_" to separate two words, it's the convention: "LAMBEG_DRUM"

Comment: I am using enum to do achieve this for single keyword string, is there any better approach?

Comment: @WAnant u said u cant use "_" or LAMBEGDRUM, then what about LAMBEG1DRU...if that doesn't work try LAMBEG2DRUM.. there are endless possibilities. problem? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your enum with a field and constructor.

```
 public enum InstrumentType{

        GUITAR("Guitar"),
        BANJO("Banjo")

        private final String name;

        private InstrumentType(String name) {
           this.name = name;          
        }

        public String toString(){
           return this.name;
        }

}
```