# Java Enum with space and shortcode value

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum in which I need to set the country in the web page.
Similar to this page - [Java enum elements with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389150/java-enum-elements-with-spaces)

```
//    sample
INDIA("India"),
RUSSIA("Russia"),
NORTH_AMERICA("North America");
```

I want the user to see "North America" in the dropdown.
But I need to pass "NA" to the database.
I tried the following. But getting the shortcode(IND,RUS,NA) in the dropdown.
IND("India"),
RUS("Russia"),
NA("North America");

Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Comment: North America is a country? Huh, I think you have a bug, and it's abunch of Canadians saying `eh! - where's Rob Ford when youneed him?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an enum like this, where you use the `name` when displaying it in dropdown and the `code`, when passing to the DB.

```
enum Country {

    INDIA("India", "IND"), RUSSIA("Russia", "RUS"), NORTH_AMERICA(
            "North America", "NA");

    private String name;
    private String code;

    Country(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    // Getters and other methods for name and code
}
```

Comment: I would make the fields `final` too

Answer (score 1):

you should try with variables inside the enum.
So your enum should be like this

```
public enum Country {

    INDIA("India","IND"),
    RUSSIA("Russia","RUS"),
    NORTH_AMERICA("North America","NA");

    private String country;
    private String shortCode;

    private Country(String country, String shortCode) {
    this.country = country;
    this.shortCode = shortCode;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public String getShortCode() {
        return shortCode;
    }
}
```